# How can I stream audio files (mp3) from Aws s3?

Tags: amazon-s3, audio-streaming

I have a simple javascript player, and I would like to stream audio files (mp3) from aws s3 sdk (Php). 
The files are **private** so I should also do the authentication.

If I banally insert the public link of the mp3 file into the src of the html object, the stream works.

Tnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to stream through php backend. You can generate Presigned url with php code and send it to the front end. It will be accessible for the limited time.

**Sample PHP Code:**

```
//Creating a presigned request
$s3Client = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
    'profile' => 'default',
    'region'  => 'us-east-1',
    'version' => '2006-03-01',
]);

$cmd = $s3Client->getCommand('GetObject', [
    'Bucket' => 'my-bucket',
    'Key'    => 'testKey'
]);

$request = $s3Client->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+20 minutes');
$presignedUrl = (string) $request->getUri();
```

**Reference:**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/s3-presigned-url.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: You run this code on your side to get url from amazon? Where does new Aws\S3\S3Client come from? is this a downloadable package? What is testKey?